# Agree to "terms and conditions" before downloading a file

Tags: terminology, checkboxes, terms-of-service

What is the terminology used to describe a mechanism that requires the user to accept specific terms and conditions before downloading a file?

For example, given a web page with a list of files on it, when the user clicks on one of the filenames they are shown the website terms of use, they must check a check box marked with "I agree", which then enables a download button. When they press the download button the files starts to download.

What is this called?

I'm trying to find a way to describe this in the same way that I can use the phrase "login form" to describe a mechanism that requires a user to login before accessing files, but the situation described above is not a login form, what can I call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [clickthrough agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickwrap) or clickwrap ;)